# Can No Longer Load rgdal

Tags: r, ubuntu, gdal, rgdal

I updated my GDAL to 2.2.2 on Ubuntu and now `rgdal` fails in R.  I get this message when I try to load `rgdal` (I also tried to update `rgdal`, but didn't work).

```
Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
  lazy-load database '/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rgdal/R/rgdal.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(method, envir = home) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
3: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgdal’
```

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing `rgdal`?

Comment: @Tung Yes, I tried to re-install `rgdal`, but it did nothing.  I fixed the issue by just updating the headers.

Comment: Did you fix it?  Please add your solution as answer!

Comment: @ott-toomet I don't think I can answer, I don't see a link to do so anyways.  I ran this `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable &&
sudo apt update &&
sudo apt upgrade` Although, now I'm getting errors I never got before, ugh...  I'm getting an error that my proj4string is not valid, which never happened in the past and that works in QGIS.

Comment: OK, so it's more like a hack that works.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue by deleting my corrupt rgdal installation, and simply reinstalling.

The warning message should indicate where it the folder is located (in your case `/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rgdal`)

In your terminal, you can delete the installed version with

`rm -rf path/to/rgdal`

where `path/to/rgdal` will be specific to your system and version.  Then reinstall in R with `install.packages('rgdal')`

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by updating and upgrading my system :

```
sudo apt update & sudo apt upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
remove.packages("rgdal")
install.packages("rgdal")
library(rgdal)
```

Comment: This worked for me but open with closing and opening Rstudio after installing

Answer (score 0):

#### What worked for me

1. Open terminal
2. Run `brew install gdal` (this step may take a few minutes)

- Note: After step 2, it may give an error if you already had it installed (that happened to me). If you get this error, run `brew upgrade gdal` (may take a few more minutes)

3. Reinstall rgdal from source, with:

```
install.packages("rgdal", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

4. Restart your R session (i.e. close and reopen RStudio) - you cannot skip this step

Now try `library(rgdal)` - it should succeed!

#### Other things to try

If the above steps don't work, try any of the following:

- Download the rgdal package source and compiling manually by [going to CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) and downloading the source (click on the link outlined [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKedu.jpg)), then install by running `install.packages("path/to/downloaded/file/rgdal_1.5-23.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")`

  - Close and reopen RStudio and that may help
- Also worth trying to manually delete the corrupted file (e.g. with `rm /Users/$USER/Library/R/4.0/library/rgdal/R/rgdal.rdb`), then running `install.packages("rgdal", repos = NULL, type="source")`, closing and reopening RStudio.
- If all of that doesn't work, one last thing is to try `install.packages("rgdal", repos="https://mac.R-project.org")`, close and reopen RStudio, and hopefully `library(rgdal)` succeeds.

Hope some of these notes helps someone else with this problem!